# The Shrinkwrap modifier doesn't work as expected on the Auxiliary Target

Tags: shrinkwrap

Is there a trick to get Shrink Wrap with Project option working correctly in for example @6:56 in the following instructional video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YksPYPa05LM

Here is an image of what I'm seeing and can't seem to figure out why it's not projecting correctly:
[image: Sample Shrink Wrap Projection]

[image: Sample Shrink Wrap Xray Object Mode]

[image: Sample Shrink Wrap Xray Edit Mode]

- I have tried moving the plane in +- the x direction
- I have tried moving the cylinder in +- the x direction
- I have tried resizing the plane and the cylinder

Comment: Hello, PPL.. Since you're asking about the _Shrinkwrap_ modifier,  it would be a good idea to revise your illustration to show the _Shrinkwrap_ settings. Maybe switch on the wireframe on the modified plane, too, so we can see its topology.

Comment: @RobinBetts Thanks for the suggestion. See extra attachment

Comment: Your plane needs to be above both objects to behave like in the reference video. Try to move it up.

Comment: @MrA, not sure what you mean. I added an extra photo displaying 'Edit Mode' showing you that the plane is above the objects.

Comment: @RobinBetts Bingo! That was it. I had to apply the scales. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds good @RobinBetts.  Does anyone have a recommendation to upload blend files for this forum to share when I have a question about them?

Comment: @PPL We have a standard method on BSE: https://blend-exchange.com/ . Follow the instructions there, and paste the generated link into your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Between us, we seem to have established that object-level Scale transforms do not play well with the 'Auxiliary Target' mechanism in the *Shrinkwrap* modifier.

So,  Ctrl-A > Apply the scales of your objects.

You should always avoid object-level scaling during modelling, but it does seem reasonable to expect to be able to animate this effect with object-level transforms. I can see that the modifier, in this case, has to know about the transforms of objects other than its owner, which might make dependencies tricky for ray-casting, but think it *should* be able to be handled, and therefore this may qualify as a bug?